# What's iPhone camera's default video fromat?

Tags: android, iphone, ios

What's the default video format of iPhone Camera. I know that compression is H.264 but what's the type of video.. flv, mp4 etc?  Same question for Android.

Comment: it is a `.mov` format

Comment: Thanks @Rstar. Can we change the format to MP4?

Comment: The default format is MP4 for android camera video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default format is **.mov** of iPhone camera video.

Comment: Thanks. Can we change it to MP4?

Comment: Yes it can be changed.

Comment: MOV is very similar to MP4, Just change the extension from .mov to .mp4 and it will work fine